# Parsing an RFC 822 (email) formatted datetime in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a data frame column containing strings in the RFC 822 date-time format used in emails. For example:

`Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)`

How do I parse these into a column of `Date`  objects?

I think it's something like `format(x, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)")` but I haven't gotten it working successfully. I'm fine using any package (e.g. `lubridate`).

Comment: `format` is for going from datetime classes to strings, not the other way around. You need `as.POSIXct` or `strptime`, e.g. `as.POSIXct('Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)', format = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")`

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I was using the wrong function. `as.POSIXct` seems to work. I posted an answer using this. Feel free to add your own answer if you want credit or you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`as.POSIXct` seems to work. I applied this to the data frame column using `mutate` from `dplyr`:

```
df <- mutate(df, dates = as.POSIXct(dates, format = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"))
```